# Reading object using fstream in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use `fstream` to write an object to a file and read it after but when I try to show the object read on the screen using cout the error message `Segmentation fault: 11` appears. Someone could help me with this code? Thanks in advance!

```
Produto *p1 = new Produto(1, "Refrigerante");

cout << "Produto p1 (pre serializacao): (" << p1->codigo << ") " << p1->descricao << endl;

ofstream serializationWriter;
serializationWriter.open("myobject.dat", ios::binary);
serializationWriter.write((char *)&p1, sizeof(p1));

Produto *p2;

ifstream serializationReader;
serializationReader.open("myobject.dat", ios::binary);
serializationReader.read((char *)&p2, sizeof(p2));

cout << "Produto p2 (pos serializacao): (" << p2->codigo << ") " << p2->descricao << endl;
```

Comment: use boost serialization! it is super awesome: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Comment: `&p2` is a pointer to a pointer, a `Produto**`. You probably want to make `p2` an instance as in `Produto p2`.

Comment: don't you also need to close the file after `write`?

Comment: `serializationWriter.write((char *)&p1, sizeof(p1));`  The name of that variable is a misnomer.  You are not "serializing" the data -- all you're doing is just taking a blob of bytes and writing it to a file.  You don't serialize non-POD objects this way.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, it is worse. He's writing only a pointer to the file and reading the same numerical value of the pointer into `p2`

Comment: @RSahu - Funny how no one who "serializes" data this way takes a look at the file they've created in an editor.  They would see right away that no program under the sun would be able to convert the gibberish in that file back into valid data.

Comment: Thank you all guys! @vsoftco you're right, I just put the CLOSE command and the code starts to work. Also thank you guys for extra informations, it helps me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You need provide some serialization mechanism for class Produto. For example:

```
class Produto {
  // ...
private: 
  std::string m_str;
private: 
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const Produto& obj);
  friend istream& operator>>(istream& stream, Prodoto& obj)
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const Produto& obj)
{
  // Write all data to stream.
  // ...
  stream << obj.m_str;
  return stream;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& stream, Prodoto& obj)
{
  // Read all data from strem.
  // ...
  stream >> obj.m_str;
  return stream; 
}
```

And then use it as below:

```
Produto p1(1, "Refrigerante");
ofstream serializationWriter;
// ...
serializationWriter << p1;

Produto p2;
ifstream serializationReader;
// ...
serializationReader >> p2;
```

For more details see [overload ostream istream operator](http://cppe.ru/index.php/C%2B%2B_Tutorial/Operator_Overloading/overload_ostream_istream_operator)